# Fly problem in my condo

Tags: pest-control, insect

so for the past month I've had these little flies in my condominium. I cannot for the life of me figure out where they are coming from, and I am trying to find out what type of flies they are. I've tried fruit fly traps, I've tried trapping them with bread and killing them when they sit on the bread, but they keep on coming.

I first noticed them inside my garbage can (which has a lid). I noticed maggots at the bottom of the can (the things that look like eggs) so I threw the can away. Now, I don't have a garbage can- I just put the food in a plastic bag and throw it away each night.

I have also noticed them in my freezer now too, they are somehow crawling in. They seem to hangout at my desk the most, which is where I have a big window.

So I am thinking three things: 1- they are coming from outside, 2- they are coming in from my kitchen sink drain (I have a seized up garbage disposal, maybe that's a factor too, although I never seen them come out of the drain, or 3- they are hiding under the carpet or something, or in a cabinet (not sure if possible).

I attached a photo of one that I killed today, if anybody can tell what type of fly it is please let me know. And of course, any suggestions on how to handle.

Thanks!!

[image: photo from today]

Comment: You can look online, or check with a university, agricultural school agricultural extension for help.

Comment: Throwing out the garbage can seems like it was a bit on the drastic side. Giving it a thorough washing with soap and hot water would have probably been enough. Spraying it down with a bleach/water solution and letting that soak overnight with a rinse in the morning should have been enough for an added comfort factor.

Comment: Are they fruit fly sized? The shape looks more like a house fly to me. Anyway what I do for flies is to spray this stuff: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Ortho-Home-Defense-Insect-Killer-for-Indoor-Perimeter-2-Ready-To-Use-022131005/300569223 (Ortho Home Defense Insect Killer, Bifenthrin 0.0500% and Zeta-Cypermethrin 0.0125%) on the windows where they congregate. They will eat it and die quickly enough to kill off the colony even if you don't find where they're laying their eggs.

Answer (score 0):

Those commercial fruit fly traps suck.  If they are in fact fruit flies you can eradicate most of them using borax.  The flies will consume the concoction detailed below and kill them.  Fruit flies breed very quickly.  You will need to continue this process for some time.

Mix one teaspoon borax with three teaspoons of sugar.  Add just enough water to dissolve the powder.  Add a teaspoon of beer, wine, lemon or lime juice as an attractant.
Cut a kitchen sponge into a 1" x 1" cube and place in a shallow flat bottomed bowl or saucer.  Add enough liquid to cover about 1/2 the sponge but leaving the top of the sponge exposed.  The fruit flies will land on the sponge and consume the liquid.  Most will be dead by the morning.

Fruit flies reproduce quickly.  You will need to place these in all the rooms with flies.  I get them in the kitchen and bathroom. Continue to make new liquid every other day as they like it fresh.

Fruit flies like to spook easily.  Place these traps in the back corner of your kitchen behind some jars to set them at ease.

Another good tip is to catch and release.  Place your vegetable and fruit scraps in a kitchen top yard waste container.  Place some fruit waste in the container.  Prop the lid with a chopstick - just enough to make a small gap and leave over night.  In the morning pull the chopstick out fast and seal the container.  Open the container outside away from your house or put the contents in the bin outside.  Repeat daily.

Where I live we have yard and food waste recycling.  This is a breeding ground for fruit flies.  The borax concoction can be make in bulk, added to a spray bottle, and sprayed on the food waste daily.  The borax will clog your spray bottle so clean it out after use and rinse with water.

Comment: "Catch and release" sounds all friendly and stuff, but just transfers the problem to someone else. How far away do you have to go to keep them from flying right back into an open window!

Comment: Best to use a holistic approach and use borax bait inside, catch and release inside, and a borax soaking of the outside bin.  Fly paper set near the propped open food container get a few as well.  I am unaware of the top air-speed velocity of an unladen fruit fly but there is a bat, swallow, and spider zone for them the pass through.

Comment: African or European? ;)